# Cannot find or change some keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I know 2 ways that a user can change Shortcuts in Ubuntu.

- Settings | keyboard Shortcuts | ...
- dconf Editor

But sometimes, it's not that easy to find out what a shortcut is or how to change it.

My current example:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>: this changes the size of the active window, but how to change it?

I was often struggling in such situations. Therefore, I hope someone could give me an idea, how to find out where a shortcut is set.

**Update**
I guess, a gap still open in the answer.
I m searching for a shortcut

```
gsettings list-recursively  | grep '>T'
```

This must list all shortcuts with the 'T', but i think it does not.

When I try to set a combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in a tool for a shortcut, the tool does not receive the combinations.

I tried a shortcut that is already reserved like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> - open a Terminal. The tool does not receive the combinations at all. The same happens with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

So, my original question looks like still open, how can i find all combinations?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `gsettings list-recursively`.
That should list your application settings, same as seen in dconf.

Maybe try grep a pattern like the key combination `grep '<Alt><Control>s'`.
The key order is not that consistent and you might need try some more variant or less strict pattern like `grep '>s'`.

I don't have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on my machine but here is a similar example when grep for '>u' on my machine.

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep '>u'
org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey ['<Control><Shift>u']
```

Then I can check this path `org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji` in `dconf-edidor`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: To jump on this answer: It's super annoying that the keyboard shortcuts in gnome settings doesn't list all the settings so that you can manually disable or change certain specific values. When you've found the correct `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` or whatever it is you're looking for, you can set the value with e.g., `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Super><Alt>Up']" `.
In my case, I like multi-cursor in Rstudio, and gnome settings doesn't list "switch to workspace up" (or down), which would be fine if it didn't also pinch the shortcut for itself.